# How to extract first and last strings in a sequence?

Tags: python

I am new to python programming..can someone suggest some way to do the following:

The whole data is stored in a file and comes . And I can not disturb the sequence.

I want to extract out the first and last nodes of the chains.There are several such chains like this. And the data content is in Giga Byte.

I am clueless about how to go about it in python. Can someone be kind enough to help.

Comment: You mean there's a lot of data .. oh, ok, thanks. Can you explain how these are chains, it is not clear to me from reading the question how the data structure works.

Comment: How is `a1=hi` related to `b1=hello`?

Comment: What if there's another pair of lines at the end saying `a1=python` and `b1=stupid programming language`. Do you want to output both `('hi', 'good programming language')` _and_ `('hi', 'stupid programming language')`?

Comment: @user1354510, yes, you want to output both `'hi`' and `'stuipid programming language`', ok. But do you want __both pairs__? In other words can chains share prefixes? I can't tell from your response.

Comment: Ok, another question: what if an `a1`/`b1` pair links back to a pair earlier in its chain. Is that link invalid? How do we deal with cycles?

Comment: Is [user1355603](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1355603/user1355603) your classmate?  You both have questions on "large graphs", you both have c++ questions, and you both have a question where you have a large file in the form of "a1=something, b1=something".  Is this homework help?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I don't know the person. And I am not a student now...so there is no question of someone being my classmate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with looking into what a "list" is, such as.

```
data[0]=hi
data[1]=hello
data[2]=how
data[3]=to
data[4]=hello
data[5]=python
data[6]=format
data[7]=computer
data[8]=python
data[9]=good programming language
```

or

a multidimensional list, depending on your data.

```
data[0][0]=hi
data[0][1]=hello
data[0][2]=how
data[0][3]=to

data[1][0]=hello
data[1][1]=python
data[1][2]=format
data[1][3]=computer
data[1][4]=python
data[1][5]=good programming language
```

Comment: Posting code which doesn't actually work is unlikely to help the OP

Answer (score 1):

I’m not exactly sure how your sequence works, especially how the start and the end element is chosen. So what I did is basically that I set a starting value which is then matched once and after that it tries to find the same values over and over again.

First of all I made a generator for the data. As you mentioned, you have quite a lot of data, so you’ll probably have some kind of sequential generator for the lines. I emulated that with a static generator yielding the example lines:

```
>>> def dataReader():
        yield 'a1=hi'
        yield 'b1=hello'
        yield 'a1=how'
        yield 'b1=to'
        yield 'a1=hello'
        yield 'b1=python'
        yield 'a1=format'
        yield 'b1=computer'
        yield 'a1=python'
        yield 'b1=good programming language'
```

Then I set up an empty list that will hold the result and the last element, which is initialized to the starting value

```
>>> lst = []
>>> last = 'hi' # as we want to begin with 'hi' which does not have a duplicate?
```

Next I walk through the data, split by the equals sign and compare the last value. I am using the value `None` to mark that the previous value already found its duplicate. To make it a bit simpler I completely ignore the `key` for now, but you could easily add more conditions if you need to make sure that the previous key is different from the current when matching the new value.

```
>>> for line in dataReader():
        key, value = line.split('=')
        if last == None:
            lst.append(line)
            last = value
        elif last == value:
            lst.append(line)
            last = None
>>> lst
['a1=hi', 'b1=hello', 'a1=hello', 'b1=python', 'a1=python', 'b1=good programming language']
```